# Optional JMX ManagedOperationParameter

Tags: java, jmx

Is there a way to have an optional ManagedOperationParameter? If I just declare one but don't pass it I get a `This command expects '1' argument(s), but was given '0'`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have an optional ManagedOperationParameter? If I just declare one but don't pass it I get a This command expects '1' argument(s), but was given '0'.

No, there is no way to do that.  How about turning your optional parameter into an `Object` type (like `Integer` instead of `int`) and then pass in null if you don't want to pass in the param.

A better mechanism would be to have 2 method calls -- one with the param and one without.  Then the method with 0 params can call the method with 1 param with null or the default value.